# How do I subscribe to a "window move" event in the Atom edtor?

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I want to subscribe to the window moving event that `electron` provides, but I don't know how to code it in an `atom` package.

When I was reading the [electron docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-move) I found an example that I think is similar to what I want:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.on('move', (e) => {
  // . . .
})
```

But this appears to require creating a new `electron` window, and I don't know how to get the current `BrowserWindow` in an existing `atom` window.

I also can hook into the `window.onresize` event in `atom`, but there is no `window.onmove`.

Lastly, I found a way to get the window position in the [atom docs](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.18.0/AtomEnvironment#instance-getPosition), but I don't know how that would be useful without polling.

Comment: according to the electron docs, you should be able to subscribe to the event as `atom.window.addEventListener('moved', ...)` but I tested it and it didn't work.

Comment: I can't get it to work either.  Where did you find that doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we should note that according to the [official documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-move), there are two events, `move` and `moved`. The latter is labeled as MacOS only.

In order to listen to the event need to fetch the current window. On the client side this can be done like this

```
const electron = require('electron');
const currentWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();

currentWindow.on('move', function() {
    // Do move event action
});
```

On the application side there is no remote, so the window is fetched this way

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const currentWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

currentWindow.on('move', function() {
    // Do move event action
});
```